# TCL ERROR: missing close-brace: possible unbalanced brace in comment

Tags: vim, tcl, braces

I am getting this TCL error

`ERROR: missing close-brace: possible unbalanced brace in comment`

and have no idea where the unbalanced brace may be. Could you please suggest some way of finding it? Maybe a program which will check braces in some files and show the place where is it. I am using vim. It would be great if vim could show this kind of things.

Vim version `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Mar 14 2012 14:58:45)`

The error is in tcl source files. I am not using any vim plugin.

Comment: While the error message indicates only a possibility of having an unbalanced brace in a comment, not the fact, the ["Why can I not place unmatched braces in Tcl comments"](http://wiki.tcl.tk/462) wiki page is worth reading to understand what the problem might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default <kbd>%</kbd> (in normal mode) should jump to the closing/opening brace or bracket when your cursor is on a brace or bracket.

So you could manually try out to find where it is, but it can be rather inefficient if the file is big.

Don't forget that with `/(` and then n you should be able to quickly jump from brace to brace.

Vim should have a default tcl syntax file installed by default, so if it not already the case, you should add in your `.vimrc`

```
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```

Comment: A way to leverage `%` is to put an extra bracket at the start and end of the file and to see if they match up. Or, given the error message, to put a close-curly-brace at the end and to see what that actually matches with. (The advantage? Removing the extra brackets/brace is really very easy…)

Answer (score 0):

There was an open curly braces "{" left in my comment (comments start with a #), when I removed the open curly brace, the error disappeared and I was left baffled.